# How to extract text from a html form drop-down options?

Tags: html, web-scraping, text-extraction

Recently I'm building a website where I need data of all car types and models, such an example with the data type is [sellanycar.com](https://uae.sellanycar.com/#).

I need all the data from 'Select Make' and corresponding 'Select Model'  dropdowns:
[image]

The code of any language is acceptable but javaScript/jQuery or Python is preferable and the data can be of any format e.g. JSON or XLXS, etc.

Comment: since it is your first post, I did it for you, please embed images, instead of linking them, in your future posts.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service, this is a Q&A site. please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn which questions are acceptable here, and how to ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) In JS/Node, you can use [Pupeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to scrape pages, and [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/), do extract what you want JQuery-style.

B) You could use a scraping tool such as [Screaming Frog](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/), to do the same, and set upp XPATH or REGEX extractions. I wrote a small piece on how to set up [custom regex extractions](https://netwell.digital/https-mixed-content-crawler-check/#mixed-content-extraction-screaming-frog), which might help, should you choose this option.